# How to display a list of dynamically loaded components in nextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js

So in my homepage I am building a list of decks per category.
Something like:

Category A:

Deck 1 | Deck 2 | Deck 3

Category B:

Deck 4 | Deck 6

Category C:

Deck 7

I know how I can load all categories from the server in my homepage, but I don't know how to load the deck lines per category.
I imagine I would be best served with a component that receives as a parameter the categoryName, and outputs the list of decks.

How I list my categories:

```
// Import the dependency.
import clientPromise from '../mongodb-client';

async function fetchCategoriesFromDB(context, session) {
  const client = await clientPromise;
  const collection = await client.db().collection('categories');
  let mySort= {name: 1};
  const categories= await collection.find().sort(mySort).toArray();
  const categoryList = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(categories));
  return categoryList;
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
const categoryList = session ? await fetchCategoriesFromDB(session): '';

return {
    props: {
      categoryList,
    }
  }
}

export default function Home({categoryList}) {

  const [categories, setCategories] = useState(categoryList);
  
  // When rendering client side don't display anything until loading is complete
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && loading) return null

  // If no session exists, display access denied message
  if (!session) { return  <Layout><AccessDenied/></Layout> }

  // If session exists, display content
  const isAdmin = session.user.email === process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_EMAIL_ADMIN;

  return (
    <Layout>

      <Head>
        <title>CardX</title>
        <meta name="description" content="A Card Repository" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>


     <div className={styles.grid}>
        
        {categories.map(({_id, name, description, url }) => (
          <div className={styles.categoryItem} key={_id} >
            
              {url && <img src={url} class={styles.category} /> }
              {name}
              <br />
              {description}
              <CategoryDecks categoryName={name} />
           </div>
          ))}
         
      </div>

...
```

And how I imagined my component to be:

```
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'

async function fetchCategoryDecksFromDB(categoryName) {

    const client = await clientPromise;
    const collection = await client.db().collection('decks');  
    let mySort= {name: 1};
    const decks= await coldecks.find({categories:categoryName}).sort(mySort).toArray();
    const deckList = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(decks));
    return deckList;
  }


  export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    const deckList = await fetchCategoryDecksFromDB(context.categoryName);
    
    return {
        props: {
          deckList,
        }
      }
    }

    export default function CategoryDecks({deckList}){

    return(<>
    <div className={styles.categoryLine}>
  
      {deckList.map(({ _id, name, description, url }) => (
        <div className={styles.card} key={_id} >
          <a href={"/decks/"+_id} >
            {url && <img src={url} class={styles.deck} /> }
            {name}<br /> 
            {description}
          </a>
         </div>
        ))}
       
    </div> </>)
  
  }
```

The thing is:

- I don't think I can call getServerSideProps from inside the component and don't know how to do it any other way. (What ways can there be to fetch the data for the component?)
- I don't know how to pass arguments to the component and use them there (Do I need dynamic import for this?)

Answer (score 0):

For now, following https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/client-side, instead of using a component I opted to put everything in the same page:

```
import Head from "next/head";
import styles from "../styles/Home.module.css";
import { useState } from "react";
import Layout from "../components/layout";
import { useSession, getSession } from "next-auth/client";
import AccessDenied from "../components/access-denied";
import React from "react";
import useSWR from "swr";

("use strict");

// Import the dependency.
import clientPromise from "../mongodb-client";

/*import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
    
    const CategoryDecks = dynamic(() => import('../components/categoryDecks'))
    */
async function fetchCategoriesFromDB(context, session) {
  const client = await clientPromise;
  const collection = await client.db().collection("categories");
  let mySort = { name: 1 };
  const categories = await collection.find().sort(mySort).toArray();
  const categoryList = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(categories));
  return categoryList;
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const session = await getSession(context);
  const categoryList = session ? await fetchCategoriesFromDB(session) : "";

  return {
    props: {
      categoryList,
    },
  };
}

const fetcher = (...args) => fetch(...args).then((res) => res.json());

function CategoryDecks({ categoryName }) {
  const { data, error } = useSWR(
    "/api/categories/" + categoryName + "/decks",
    fetcher
  );

  if (error) return <div>Failed to load</div>;
  if (!data) return <div>Loading...</div>;

  return (
    <div className={styles.categoryLine}>
      {data.map(({ _id, name, description, url }) => (
        <div className={styles.card} key={_id}>
          <a href={"/decks/" + _id}>
            {url && <img src={url} class={styles.deck} />}
            {name}
          </a>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default function Home({ cardList, deckList, categoryList }) {
  const [session, loading] = useSession();
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState(categoryList);

  // When rendering client side don't display anything until loading is complete
  if (typeof window !== "undefined" && loading) return null;

  // If no session exists, display access denied message
  if (!session) {
    return (
      <Layout>
        <AccessDenied />
      </Layout>
    );
  }

  // If session exists, display content
  const isAdmin = session.user.email === process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_EMAIL_ADMIN;

  return (
    <Layout>
      <Head>
        <title>CardX</title>
        <meta name="description" content="A Card Repository" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <div>
        {categories.map(({ _id, name, description, url }) => (
          <>
            <div className={styles.categoryLine} key={_id}>
              {url && <img src={url} class={styles.category} />}
              {name}
            </div>
            <CategoryDecks categoryName={name} />
          </>
        ))}
      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
}
```